# How to extract maximum date from a list of random dates, grouped by week, month, quarter or year?

Tags: c#, linq, date, calendar

Given a list of random dates, is there an elegant C# way (LINQ or otherwise) to extract the last date in the list, grouped by week, month, quarter or year?

I hope that's clear but if not, using this example set of dates:

- Mon 01/01/2018
- Tue 02/01/2018
- Thu 04/01/2018
- Tue 09/01/2018
- Thu 11/01/2018
- Fri 12/01/2018
- Mon 22/01/2018
- Tue 23/01/2018
- Wed 24/01/2018
- Wed 31/01/2018
- Thu 01/02/2018
- Tue 27/02/2018

Extracting maximum by week would yield

- Thu 04/01/2018 = the last date in the first week in the sample
- Fri 12/01/2018 = the last date in the second week in the sample
- Wed 24/01/2018 = etc.
- Thu 01/02/2018
- Tue 27/02/2018

And extracting maximum by month would yield

- Wed 31/01/2018 = the last date in January in the sample
- Tue 27/02/2018 = the last date in February in the sample

I need to be able to do this extraction by week number, calendar month, calendar quarter and calendar year.

I'm not even sure how to begin this.  So at present I have no code to share.

Any ideas will be very welcome.

**CLARIFICATION:** the weekday names are included here for the benefit of us humans.  My actual date is proper `DateTime` types.  So the code doesn't need to parse Strings to DateTimes.

Additionally, I can easily write something like this without LINQ.  But what I am hoping for is an elegant solution using LINQ or some other clever trick.

Comment: Even with LINQ, this will be quite complicated :( But not impossible :)

Comment: This might give you an idea: http://rextester.com/JBA49267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using LINQ. Here the example for grouping by **month**:

```
var grouped = dates.OrderBy(x => x.Ticks).GroupBy(x => x.Month)
                   .Select(x => new {Month = x.Key, Max = x.Max()});
```

This gives for your example:

> { Month = 1, Max = 1/31/2018 12:00:00 AM }
>
> { Month = 2, Max = 2/27/2018 12:00:00 AM }

---

To do this for the **week** instead, use this lambda for the `GroupBy`:

```
x => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
         x, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday
     )
```

Output:

> { Week = 1, Max = 1/4/2018 12:00:00 AM }
>
> { Week = 2, Max = 1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM }
>
> { Week = 4, Max = 1/24/2018 12:00:00 AM }
>
> { Week = 5, Max = 2/1/2018 12:00:00 AM }
>
> { Week = 9, Max = 2/27/2018 12:00:00 AM }

---

For the **quarter**:

```
x => (x.Month + 2)/3
```

Output:

> { Quarter = 1, Max = 2/27/2018 12:00:00 AM }

---

For the **year**:

```
x => x.Year
```

Output

> { Year = 2018, Max = 2/27/2018 12:00:00 AM }

Comment: What happens when there are other years in the data source?  Grouping by month won’t give you the expected result then

Comment: Beautiful!  I learned something valuable here.  Thank you very much!  BTW how do you do the cool yellow formatting here?  Is there markup for it or do you use HTML?

Comment: @maccettura how about `GroupBy(x => x.Year + x.Month/12)` or `GroupBy(x => x.Year + x.Month/100)`

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this in C# which can be adapted for any other grouping required

```
    public static Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, DateTime> MaxByYearMonth(this List<DateTime> sourceDateTimes)
    {
        IEnumerable<DateTime>                             ordered = sourceDateTimes.OrderBy(x => x.Ticks);
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<Tuple<int, int>, DateTime>> grouped = ordered.GroupBy(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.Year, x.Month));
        Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, DateTime>             maxed   = grouped.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Max());
        return maxed;
    }
```